# Need to create a primary key by the combination of 4 fields to determine a price

Tags: apex, formula, formula-field

I need to create a primary key with combination of 4 fields, i.e. Product  + Sales Unit Of Measure + Currency + Province.

If any of the 4 fields differ, it will result in a different price for the product.

Currently the logic goes just for the region. But currently the country I have been working for is maintaining price on the basis of Sales unit of Measure.

I have added fields on the standard price page.
But how do i form a primary key with the combination of these fields?

Comment: Can you elaborate more on "primary key to determine a price" ? For now I can't  linked this two concepts, as primary key just determines uniqueness of record.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a formula field that combines the fields like this:

```
Field1 + '#' + Field2 + '#' + Fiel.... ect.
```

Then you can query that value resulting in the unique record that stores the price of the product.

Comment: Query as in how do I query ?

Comment: You have write a small Apex trigger for that.

Comment: I am sorry , I am not getting logic